# Как развернуть веб-проект на PHP в Virtual Azure Machine?

Tags: azure

Как развернуть веб-проект на PHP в Virtual Azure Machine? 
Сейчас создан виртуальный сервер, а как развернуть в нем PHP проект - не нахожу

Comment: Погоди, тебе надо развернуть его в виртуальной машине или в Cloud Service? Это разные вещи. Если в VM, то так же, как и на обычном сервеве - устанавливаешь веб сервер и разворачиваешь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Необходимо взять виртуальную машину из коллекции или взять чистую VM. В дизайне портала внизу кнопка добавить (после перехода в пункт меню виртуальные машины).
2. При создании виртуальной машины по умолчанию создастся облачная служба (если в настройках создания не выбрать существующую).
3. Я рекомендую брать машину UbuntuServer.
4. После установки виртуальной машины подключитесь к ней по ssh. По умолчанию используется пользователь azureuser и пароль, заданный вами при установке.
5. Подымите и настройте Apache/Nginx, PHP, Mysql и все, что вам необходимо.
6. В настройках созданной облачной службы вы увидите DNS имя, это DNS имя позволит вам обращаться к облачной службе (и виртуальной машине по умолчанию). DNS имя выглядит как - yourname.cloudapp.com
7. На виртуальной машине настройте виртуальные хосты.
8. Пропишите соответствующие настройки в Ваше доменное имя.

Надеюсь, помог, спасибо. )

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, если вы хотите развернуть PaaS или IaaS инфраструктуру.
Если у вас уже есть готовый веб-проект, и вы не хотите тратить время на обслуживание виртуальной машины (патчи, апгрейды операционной системы, безопасность и тд), Azure Web Apps будет более примлемое решение.

Здесь описание как развернуть свой сайт на PHP: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-php?pivots=platform-windows

Вот здесь более подробное и детальное описание как развернуть на виртуальной машине: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-setup-vm-on-azure-for-php-websites/

Еще один интересный вариант, это использование готовых шаблонов (templates). Как пример, темплейт внизу дает вам полуготовое решение для запуска виртуалки на базе убунто с приустановленным  Apache2 и тд. Прекрасный вариант для валидации и демо.
https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/resources/templates/ubuntu-apache-test-page/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Просто как игра в шарики.
Нажимаете "Развернуть в Azure", логинитесь в свой Azure Portal аккаунт, заполняете параметры и легким движением руки получаете все что хотите :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле таких полуготовых решений тысячи на просторах интернета. Это был всего лишь пример. Вы можете найти более оптимальный для вашего решения.